# BigQuery: Cannot insert new value after updating several schema fields using streaming API

Tags: google-bigquery

The issue I am facing in my nodejs application is identical to this user's question: [Cannot insert new value to BigQuery table after updating with new column using streaming API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279116/cannot-insert-new-value-to-bigquery-table-after-updating-with-new-column-using-s).

To my understanding changes such as widening a table's schema may require some period of time before streamed inserts can reference the new columns otherwise a 'no such field' error is returned. For me this error is not always consistent as sometimes I am able to successfully insert.

However, I specifically wanted to know if you could alternatively use a load job instead of streaming? If so what drawbacks does it have as I am not sure of the difference even having read the documentation.

Alternatively, if I do use streaming but with the `ignoreUnknownValues` option, does that mean that all of the data is eventually inserted including data referencing new columns? Just that new columns are not queryable until the table schema is finished updating?

Comment: Are you able to create a retry mechanism? This state duration is only for a couple of minutes like 2-3 minutes only.